# Img not displaying correctly in Symfony

Tags: php, image, symfony

My twig file goes like this :

```
    Let us try to see an image :

    <img src="{{ absolute_url(asset('app/Resources/images/bulb.png')) }}" alt="Symfony!" width="42" height="42"/>

    Trying it another way :

<img src="app/Resources/images/bulb.png" alt="Symfony!" width="42" height="42"/>
```

But when I go to that page in Symfony, I see something like this :

[image]

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: What is location of twig file? @EwanDelanoy

Comment: @AnkiiG Location of twig file is app/Resources/views/

Comment: Best Practice is to Store your assets in the `web/` directory. @EwanDelanoy

Comment: Once your picture will be in your web directory, just use asset ;) 

`{{ asset('images/blub.png') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently, twig is going to be trying to find your asset in:

```
/web/app/Resources/images/bulb.png
```

use instead:
    {{ asset('@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/bulb.png', absolute=true) }}

> note the use of an additional `public` folder.  If you must store assets in `app`, then this is sensible.

However, @Ewan Delanoy is correct, you really should be storing all your assets [directly in the web folder](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/web-assets.html).

Then you can just call

```
{{ asset('images/bulb.png', absolute=true) }}
```

Comment: Got it, works now, thanks. Who said donkeys were stupid ?

Comment: quite a few people sometimes! :)